# How to set position and size of UIBarButtonItems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I know this kind of questions have been asked a lot BUT I still can not find a simple way to  implement it. 
Right now that what I have.

[image]

```
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBackground.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

   CGRect ButtonSizeframe = CGRectMake(0, 0,50,50);
  //Msg Navigator Button
UIButton *tmpButtonMsg = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[tmpButtonMsg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"msg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tmpButtonMsg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"msgPressed.png"]   forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
tmpButtonMsg.frame = ButtonSizeframe;
[tmpButtonMsg setTag:MsgBox];
[tmpButtonMsg addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonNavigationAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *msgButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tmpButtonMsg];

 //Tag Navigator Button
UIButton *tmpButtonTag = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[tmpButtonTag setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UserTagIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
tmpButtonTag.frame = ButtonSizeframe;
[tmpButtonTag setTag:Tag];
[tmpButtonTag addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonNavigationAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *tagButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tmpButtonTag];

NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:msgButton,tagButton,nil];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:myArray animated:YES];
```

I want to have both buttons square size (with toolBar Height) without space between them and Aligned to right .
I think that I read all the question on stack (I tried but didn't find an easy way to do it, what do I miss here?(Why would Apple do such obvious things like that so inconvenient or it's my fault as usual?)